# Copy/Mirror hard disk without booting into Windows

Tags: hard-drive, windows-10, mirroring

My Windows 10 is not booting up, although I can access Recovery menus with command prompt (No safeboot though). Can I mirror my OS to my external HDD with command prompt in Recovery Menu? Or is there anything else to do that? I have copied my files using robocopy to my external HDD.

Comment: Are you able to run "Launch Startup Repair"? http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/7728/troubleshot-startup-problems-with-startup-repair-tool-in-windows-7-vista/

Comment: @LunaMezza Yep, I tried that, but most options doesn't work (not yet tried reset, will do that after all data is transferred).

Comment: Macrium Reflect Free after installed on a windows PC has a boot disk you can make, boot from it and image the drive to a usb storage device...http://www.macrium.com/reflectfree.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a second pc at hand, you can download Hirens boot cd/dvd. These have the tools to boot from USB stick/CD/DVD and give you tools such as a partition manager and harddrive cloning software that you can use to do what you're asking.

Its a tool handy to have for any pc enthusiast, as it has many tools to troubleshoot/repair a defective windows installation.

It even has a mini windows so you can basically boot to a working windows installation, and manually copy the files from HDD1 to HDD2 if you wanted to.

Comment: Note, Hirens pirates software to put on their discs.   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hiren%27s_BootCD#Licensing_issues

Comment: Tnx @Moab, I use an old version, and was unaware of these issues...

Comment: I have used it plenty, best rescue disc there is, just don't advise it here, evidently they have cut down on unauthorized use of software on their discs in newer versions.

Comment: @Moab I hear you. From now on I won't be advising it here either. But then again, I may look into what the new hirens version offers and adjust my view accordingly. It is always handy to be able to boot into a working windows anyway, and the commandline utils (especially mbrfix /fixmbr is awesome)

Answer (score 1):

If you have a USB or a CD/DVD you can burn using another computer you can use [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/). It's quite easy to use despite the retro appearance. The only problem you may face is with the different naming scheme ( */dev/sda1* instead of *C:/*   -   you can google *"sda naming scheme"* if you need)
If you have another Windows machine handy you can use [YUMI](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/) to make a bootable USB drive with Clonezilla. You can even add a new partition to your external HDD and then write Clonezilla on that using YUMI. Otherwise just burn the .iso from their site to a CD/DVD.

Sorry I don't know much about Windows recovery tools so I can't say about using the cmd.

Answer (score 0):

All the above answers are good, but just in case there is no other PC/Bootable storage, you can also use `robocopy` and `diskpart` in Recovery Command Prompt (Hard to use, but sometimes the only available option).

**EDIT -**

I have made a nice little batch script than can be run from Windows Recovery->Command Prompt. This script is made for copying C: Drive (Windows Drive) and D: Drive (My Main Drive). However, more drives or drives with different names can also be added to it (Even in Windows Recovery with Notepad. And yes, Notepad is available in Windows Recovery Command Prompt).

Download the script here - [Direct Link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8UizUpBrF1YeHpxSnp5SV84RVk/view?usp=sharing) or [Shortened Link](https://goo.gl/wOaNP3) (https://goo.gl/wOaNP3)